# Magento Catalog Search - option to change like "OR" to like "AND"

Tags: catalogsearch, search, query

I´m currently working on a search extension for Magento.
I´m fairly new to the Magento framework, but I have found a serious feature lack in regards to the Catalog Search.

In Magento admin you can choose what type of search you need, e.g. "LIKE", "FULLTEXT" or "COMBINE".

When it comes to "LIKE" and "COMBINE" in both cases the search query LIKE operator is set as "OR", which in many cases give very inaccurate search results when performing multi-word searching.

As an example if you search for "windows 10" in a software shop you will get alot of unwanted results.

In my view the default operator for "LIKE" search should be "AND" instead of "OR" because in most cases, as in the example above, we want to find products containing both "windows" and "10" when searching "windows 10", and if the shop holds thousands of products it becomes a critical flaw.

I could overwrite the search model in my module, or simply create my own search query from scratch, but that is hardly optimal, if I want my module to adhere to the core Magento framework.

The optimal solution would be if the Magento developer staff would modify the search model function:

```
prepareResult($object, $queryText, $query)
```

Located at line 334 in file (Magento ver. 1.9.2.1):

```
/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php
```

And implement a select option in Magento admin config so that shop owner can choose "OR" or "AND" for LIKE and COMBINE search types, and have "AND" be default setting.

I strongly urge anyone in the Magento developer community to take this into consideration.

As it is right now I am forced to supply a guide to my customers on how to manually change the search model via FTP, if they want their "LIKE"/"COMBINE" search with "AND" operator.

Comment: Zend has Lucene built into it. Pitch Magento's MySQL based search in the wheely bin where it belongs and get a module that uses Zend Lucene for its search engine.