# Magento catalog search

Tags: magento-1.8, product, catalogsearch

I'm trying to find a product using its name on magento but it renders alot of products that have nothing in common with the product. I set to "No" the searchable parameter for all other attributes so it doesn't look in description or others to make sure i have a unique result but i don't get it.

When i search by SKU, i do get a unique result.

Is there anything I may have looped.

Comment: For `Name` attribute Did you gave `yes` for `Use in Quick Search` under `catalog > Manage > attributes` ?

Comment: This question might help you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83653/magento-catalog-search-option-to-change-like-or-to-like-and?rq=1

Comment: @BabyinMagento : Yes, i did !

Comment: @mockingbid go to `System=>Configuration=>Catalog=>Catalog Search=>Search Type`  and check with `Like, fulltype & like/Fulltype` chnage configuration & check which is better needs your requirement.

Comment: @mockingbid : Is FLAT catalog enabled ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento : The use of '" fulltext" gives far fewer results with desired product first in the list. I think that will do for now giving the way magento search works

Comment: @mockingbid yes `fulltext` give fewer results only as if you search with complete product name it will give accurate result.... but i dont think customers will do that....

Comment: @BabyinMagento : you are probably right, is this the limit of native magento search ?

Comment: you have one more option to improve search result using `Catalog > Search Terms`. but for my knowledge this is also not sufficient for large number of products.